# Question on guice construction injection when there is an additional parameter to the constructor

Tags: guice

I'm using guice-4.1.0. The output of the following code is `in b, host:`. I was expecting an error. Because nowhere was `host` explicitly given to the constructor. Any idea?

```java
package com.mycompany.app;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());
        Client client = injector.getInstance(Client.class);
        client.foo();
    }
}

class AppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {  
        bind(B.class).to(BImpl.class);
    }
}

class Client {
    private B b;

    @Inject
    public Client(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(b.foo());
    }
}

interface B {
    String foo();
}

class BImpl implements B {
    private String host;

    @Inject
    public BImpl(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String foo() {
        return "in b, host: " + host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `String` class provides and `empty constructor`. When Guice sees a String is being injected, it tries to find a binding for String or else invoke the empty constructor of the String class.

**From Java's String class code**

```
/**
 * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
 * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
 * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
 */
public String() {
    this.value = "".value;
}
```

As you can see, it sets the value to `""`. This is the reason you are seeing an empty String being printed in the output.

Try the same thing with `Integer` for example and you will get

```
Could not find a suitable constructor in java.lang.Integer. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private. at java.lang.Integer.class(Integer.java:52)
```